# Find documents in mongoDB collection by coordinates via haversine formula

Tags: mongodb, coordinates, haversine

I have this structure in my collection

```
{
    "categorie" : "Introduction",
    "quart" : "jour",
    "pdq" : 23,
    "x" : 302375.197993,
    "y" : 5046522.11601,
    "lat" : 45.5586064034326,
    "long" : -73.5310596776929,
    "date" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
}
```

I have latitude=42.5232886&longitude=-71.5923142 in query parameters.
I need to find all documents which are located at less than 3KM from the a coordinate point passed in parameter.

I am using MongoDB 3.6

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/ ? Can your use case be described by both links?

Comment: Thats it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we don't need Haversine formula in Mongodb.Here I have done with mongoose. We need to create a schema that contain type and coordinates. You can see more details in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html

> So it's has another problem with mongoose version. Mongoose v6.3.0
> worked for me. When you will use countDocuments with the query, it can
> be generate error but count function not generating any error. I know
> count deprecated, it shouldn't be use but I haven't find better
> solution. If anyone find solution for count, let me know. Also you can visit https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6981

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    location: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Point"],
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        index: "2dsphere",
      },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const MyModel = mongoose.model("rent", schema);
```

The query will be

```js
const result = await MyModel.find({
      location: {
        $near: {
          $geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [Number(filters.longitude), Number(filters.latitude)],
          },
          $maxDistance: filters.maxRadius * 1000,
          $minDistance: filters.minRadius * 1000,

        },
      },
    })
```